# Subversion Protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, svn

I'm researching the feasiblity of building the ability to browse a subversion repository from my web app.  I'm developing in asp.net.  I've read some mentions of WebDAV, but nothing that seems particularly concrete.  Does anyone know anything about the protocol that is used to communicate with SVN?  Or even better, a .net library that can do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I may have answered my own question...

Edit:  There is a new url:

http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 2):

Subversion can serve repositories using 2 different protocols. The svn:// protocol is used by svnserve, the custom Subversion server. The http:// protocol is used by the Apache version of Subversion. Apache provides the webDAV functionality that you see with HTTP.

I created a library to work on the server part. It will do stuff like

- Add and delete users
- Change user's passwords
- Create and delete repositories
- Create and delete directories

It's called SVNManagerLib and I'm hosting it at CodePlex.

http://svnmanagerlib.codeplex.com

I've used it for a couple Winform apps, but I've also used it with WCF. It only works with svnserve configurations. I haven't had time to add Apache related functionality.